# Is any way to start go_binary before java_test?

Tags: bazel

Our project has a few GRPC servers defined as **go_binary** targets. We develop client SDKs for Java and Python applications and we would like to use **java_test** and **py_test**. Is any way to start a specific **go_binary** target before **java_test** or **py_test**?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a test harness that starts the gRPC server before running the tests. For example, you could add the binary to the `data` attribute of the test, and then started it beforehand:

```
go_binary(
    name = "my_grpc_server",
    [...]
)

py_test(
    name = "my_test",
    [...]
    data = [":my_grpc_server"],
)
```

and then inside the test file:

```
class ClientTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        r = runfiles.Create()
        self.server = subprocess.Popen([r.Rlocation("path/to/my_grpc_server")])

    def tearDown(self):
        self.server.terminate()
        self.server.wait()
```

This example is very simple, you'll probably run into issues regarding the availability of the port the server listens on, or waiting for the server to start up. You could add flags to your gRPC server to allow communication over a domain socket, or make it listen on an unused port and have the test parse the port number from the server's log output.

For details on finding the server with `runfiles`: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/a7a0d48fbeb059ee60e77580e5d05baeefdd5699/tools/python/runfiles/runfiles.py#L16-L58

If you find yourself copy-pasting this pattern a lot, or having to implement it in multiple languages, you could try using an `sh_test()` rule to wrap the underlying `py_test` or `java_test`, and to start the server, then start the test with an environment variable telling it how to reach the server (eg `MY_GRPC_SERVER_ADDRESS=localhost:${test_port}`.